# How can I test that a value is within a range with a "case" statement instead of an "if" statement?

Tags: delphi, syntax, if-statement, case-statement

Can the following if statement be converted to a case statement?

```
if (Number >= 5) and (Number <= 10) then
  lblAnswer.Caption := 'in range'
else
  lblAnswer.Caption := 'out of range';
```

---

My Answer :

Yes it can

```
case (number >= 5) and (Number <= 10) of
  lblAnswer.Caption := 'in range';
  lblAnswer.Caption := 'out of range';
end;
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? For such expressions, a `if ... then` is just the clearer and faster way of doing that. There is no interest in using a `case` here.

Comment: An alternate statement : if (number in [5..10]) then .. else ..

Comment: InRange() for when limits are not constant or out of set range.

Answer (score 27):

If Number has some integer data type, then:

```
case number of
5 .. 10: lblAnswer.Caption := 'in range';
else     lblAnswer.Caption := 'out of range';
end;
```

Comment: thx so i had to leave out the long code ... and just go to numbers alrite make sense now thx alot

Comment: Of course this will only work if number is an Integer and not a floating point type.

Comment: @user1000441 if this answer solved your problem, you should mark it as "accepted answer" so others know your problem is solved.

Answer (score 8):

A small correction:

```
case (number >= 5) and (Number <= 10) of
  true:lblAnswer.Caption := 'in range';
  false:lblAnswer.Caption := 'out of range';
end;
```

Comment: +1 This is the correct way of coding it using `case` but honestly there is no interest of using a `case` here instead of a `if .. then` statement.

Comment: @peter, this code here is correct. But Arnaud means that an if then statement is more appropriate.

Comment: Either da-soft's answer or an if statement. Very odd to write case with a boolean condition. I originally thought this was syntax error it looked so weird. This answer works but you'll never see it in anyone else's code.

Comment: -1. I cannot endorse Boolean case statements. They can confuse the compiler, which in turn confuses the programmer. (For lengthy discussions on this topic, do a [newsgroup search for Boolean case statements](http://groups.google.com/groups/search?q=boolean+case+statement+kennedy), and include my name in the search terms.)

Answer (score 1):

```
Function InRange (Lo,Hi,Val : Integer) : Boolean;
Begin
 Result := (Val>=Lo)And(Val<=Hi);
End;
```